# Why can't I add a blanket impl on a trait with a type parameter?

Tags: generics, rust, traits, type-parameter

Consider these two traits:

```
pub trait Foo {
    fn new(arg: u32) -> Self;
}

pub trait Bar<P>: Foo {
    fn with_parameter(arg: u32, parameter: P) -> Self;
}
```

I'd like to add the blanket impl:

```
impl<T: Bar<P>, P: Default> Foo for T {
    fn new(arg: u32) -> Self {
        Self::with_parameter(arg, P::default())
    }
}
```

But I get the compiler error:

```
error[E0207]: the type parameter `P` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
 --> src/lib.rs:9:17
  |
9 | impl<T: Bar<P>, P: Default> Foo for T {
  |                 ^ unconstrained type parameter
```

I think I get this error because I'm violating trait coherence rules, but I don't understand exactly what rule this would break. Why is this pattern not allowed? And, more importantly, can I achieve what I want without getting an error?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that a single type could implement `Bar<P>` for multiple values of `P`. If you had a struct `Baz` that implemented `Bar<i32>` and `Bar<String>`, which type should `Foo::new` use for `P`?

The only solution is to ensure that a single type cannot implement `Bar` more than once (if that's not what you want, then you have a flaw in your design!). To do so, we must replace the `P` type parameter with an associated type.

```
pub trait Bar: Foo {
    type Parameter;

    fn with_parameter(arg: u32, parameter: Self::Parameter) -> Self;
}

impl<T> Foo for T
where
    T: Bar,
    T::Parameter: Default,
{
    fn new(arg: u32) -> Self {
        Self::with_parameter(arg, T::Parameter::default())
    }
}
```

An implementation of `Bar` would look like this:

```
struct Baz;

impl Bar for Baz {
    type Parameter = i32;

    fn with_parameter(arg: u32, parameter: Self::Parameter) -> Self {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Why do I get "the type parameter is not constrained" when creating a blanket implementation for a closure trait (Fn)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37377490/155423)

Answer (score 6):

I've broken down and extended [Francis's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42614667/155423) of why the code does not compile. I may not be the smartest kid on the block, but it took me way too long to understand his concise reasoning.

Let's create `Baz`, which implements `Bar` in 2 variants: `i32` and `String`:

```
struct Baz;

impl Bar<i32> for Baz { /* ... */ }

impl Bar<String> for Baz { /* ... */ }
```

Type dependency graph after blanket impl takes effect:

```
           -> trait Bar<i32>    -> trait Foo (with i32 baked-in)
struct Baz
           -> trait Bar<String> -> trait Foo (with String baked-in)
```

We end up with 2 different implementations of `Foo`: with baked-in `i32` and with baked-in `String`.
When we write `<Baz as Foo>::new()`, compiler can't tell which version of `Foo` we mean; they are indistinguishable.

The rule of a thumb is that trait A can have blanket implementation for trait B only if trait A is generic over all generic parameters of trait B.