# How do I declare the implementation of a function that takes a trait that has a type parameter?

Tags: rust

I have a trait with generic type. I want to define a struct with a property which meets that trait and I want to implement a function in that struct that uses the function inside the trait:

```
pub trait Point<I> {
    fn id(&self) -> I;
}

pub struct Connection<T> {
    pub to: T,
}

impl<T: Point> Connection<T> {
    pub fn is_connected_to(&self, point: T) -> bool {
        self.to.id() == point.id()
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    struct SimplePoint;
    impl Point<char> for SimplePoint {
        fn id(&self) -> char {
            return 'A';
        }
    }

    let a = SimplePoint {};

    let conn = Connection { to: a };
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d70d592fbe40a006e09a1086672dcfe1&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

If I try to run this code, I get an error:

```
error[E0243]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0
 --> src/main.rs:9:9
  |
9 | impl<T: Point> Connection<T> {
  |         ^^^^^ expected 1 type argument
```

If I try add a generic type:

```
impl<T: Point<I>> Connection<T> {
    pub fn is_connected_to(&self, point: T) -> bool {
        self.to.id() == point.id()
    }
}
```

Then I get this error:

```
error[E0412]: cannot find type `I` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:9:15
  |
9 | impl<T: Point<I>> Connection<T> {
  |               ^ did you mean `T`?
```

If I try to define the type `I`:

```
impl<I, T: Point<I>> Connection<T> {
    pub fn is_connected_to(&self, point: T) -> bool {
        self.to.id() == point.id()
    }
}
```

The compiler tells me that `I` is unconstrained:

```
error[E0207]: the type parameter `I` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
 --> src/main.rs:9:6
  |
9 | impl<I, T: Point<I>> Connection<T> {
  |      ^ unconstrained type parameter
```

How should I declare the implementation of the `is_connected_to` function?

Comment: Is it reasonable for a type to implement both `Point<char>` and (for example) `Point<i32>`? Or will every type that implements `Point` implement it only once? If the latter, you want an associated type, not a generic one. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613974/3650362

Comment: Thanks!. I've been able to write a working example using associated type. This is the link https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=adac9f30c472054e4674e2fcd973f603&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015 just in case it could help anyone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A generic type must be monomorphized: each generic type must be resolved as a concrete type. If there is no constraint, the compiler cannot know what is the concrete type you want. You must put the generic type in the function:

```
pub trait Point<I: PartialEq> {
    fn id(&self) -> I;
}

pub struct Connection<T> {
    pub to: T
}

impl<T> Connection<T> {
    pub fn is_connected_to<I: PartialEq>(&self, point: T) -> bool
    where
        T: Point<I>
    {
        self.to.id() == point.id()
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    struct SimplePoint;
    impl Point<char> for SimplePoint{
        fn id(&self) -> char { return 'A' }
    }

    let a = SimplePoint {};

    let conn = Connection {
        to: a
    };
}
```