# unconstrained type parameter error when impl Trait for arbitrary type

Tags: rust

Here is an example about [build a minimal web service in rust using hyper](https://blog.logrocket.com/a-minimal-web-service-in-rust-using-hyper/).

I post code on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c183017d1c2f1328582167606e2762d6)(It reported: unresolved import `route_recognizer`, I use `route-recognizer = "0.2"`)

In the example, there is a `Context` object.

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct AppState {
    pub state_thing: String,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Context {
    pub state: AppState,     // I would like change AppState to AppState<T> to hold any data.
    pub req: Request<Body>,
    pub params: Params,
    body_bytes: Option<Bytes>,
}
```

In the example, the main function [just use a very simple `AppState` object](https://github.com/zupzup/rust-minimal-web-service-hyper/blob/main/src/main.rs#L34).

```
let app_state = AppState {  // I would like modify AppState to a Generics to hold any data.
      state_thing: some_state.clone(),  
};

let router_capture = shared_router.clone();
async {
   Ok::<_, Error>(service_fn(move |req| {
         route(router_capture.clone(), req, app_state.clone())
   }))
}
```

I would like to change the `Context` to `Context<T>`:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Context<T> {
    pub state: AppState<T>,     // I would like change AppState to AppState<T> to hold any data.
    pub req: Request<Body>,
    pub params: Params,
    body_bytes: Option<Bytes>,
}
```

But it cause a serial problem. The main trouble is here:
the original code is [here](https://github.com/zupzup/rust-minimal-web-service-hyper/blob/main/src/router.rs#L9), I try to modify:

```
#[async_trait]
pub trait Handler<T>: Send + Sync + 'static {
    async fn invoke(&self, context: Context<T>) -> Response;  // add a type T
}

#[async_trait]
// add a type T
impl<T, F: Send + Sync + 'static, Fut> Handler for F  
where
    F: Fn(Context<T>) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future + Send + 'static,
    Fut::Output: IntoResponse,
{
    async fn invoke(&self, context: Context<T>) -> Response {
        (self)(context).await.into_response()
    }
}
```

The error is :

> the type parameter T is not constrained

I searched for several days.
Some answers is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=the%20type%20parameter%20is%20not%20constrained) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613974/why-cant-i-add-a-blanket-impl-on-a-trait-with-a-type-parameter)

My conclusion about eliminating this error:

1. use associated type.
2. use PhantomData.

But, as a new starter in Rust, I can't solve the trouble. Could anyone help to fix the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you are not showing a minimum code example that shows the error. In fact, adding the `<T>` to your sample, with a few tweaks here and there, and it compiles just fine: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=52ff983ea32d76c665c6d67d3aac5878).

Comment: I try to modify my code as your clue. but I need to add <T> everywhere. I uploaded a [minimal code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c183017d1c2f1328582167606e2762d6)

Comment: Your playground is missing a few dependencies, but adding them compiles just fine. The most useful example would be a code that works for everything except the thing you are asking about. Anyway, adding the `<T>` everywhere compiles, too [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d342cb151161326d3ca6ef1a339ad063). Maybe your question is about how to write this while avoiding to add `<T>` everywhere?

Comment: Thanks for your help. very appreciated.  By the way, the playground can't load all dependencies? I googled for a while, it says  it will use `the top 100 most downloaded crates`,  `To use a crate, add the appropriate extern crate foo line to the code`, I tried `extern crate route-recognizer`, but still got error.

Comment: I guess that `route-recognizer` is not as popular as expected. Those things happen... but for StackOverflow purposes, you can just add few mock types with a similar signature (and `todo!()` impls) because you just want to illustrate a compiler issue, no need to have a fully working example.