# Implement a trait for structs that implement another trait that is generic over structs that implement yet another trait

Tags: rust

Please don't get intimidated by the question title. What I'm trying to do is really quite simple:

```rust
use std::iter::FromIterator;

trait ElementTrait {}
trait FromIteratorTrait {}

impl<T: ElementTrait, C: FromIterator<T>> FromIteratorTrait for C {}
```

`rustc` complains about the following:

```
the type parameter `T` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
```

Can someone explain why this code produces an error and how to get around it? Thanks!

Comment: What you're missing is that a type can implement multiple `FromIterator` traits, e.g. `FromIterator<i32>` and `FromIterator<f64>`, and if `i32` and `f64` both implement `ElementTrait` it would be ambiguous which `FromIteratorTrait` applies.

Comment: Also see [Why do I get “the type parameter is not constrained” when creating a blanket implementation for a closure trait (Fn)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37377490/3650362)